# Enviar notificación cuando se edite una pregunta que voté para cerrar

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Me ha pasado *mas de una vez*:

1. Veo una pregunta con un *contenido* interesante, **pero** que falla en las formas: mal explicada, sin código de ejemplo, difícil de entender, ... En definitiva, una pregunta **que estoy interesado** en contestar.
2. Voto para cerrar la pregunta, dejando un comentario del porqué de mi voto.
3. Por algún motivo, **me pierdo** la edición de la pregunta. Es editada, se muestra en la lista de activas, **pero** yo no estoy conectado en ese momento, y, sencillamente, no puedo atender el monitor.

A partir de aquí, la pregunta sigue su curso: puede reabrirse, puede recibir respuestas (alguna, tal vez, lo suficientemente similar a la mía como para que no tenga sentido el escribirla).

- Me siento con el *deber moral*, ya que voté por su cierre, de **votar por su reapertura** cuando el motivo que propició dicho cierre sea solventado.
- Es un tema que *me atrae*, y en el que poseo ciertos conocimientos que podrían ser de ayuda para el usuario y, por extensión, para la comunidad.
- Porqué negarlo: quiero optar a los 15 puntos de la `✓ respuesta aceptada` (o algún que otro ▲*upvote*).

Una posible solución sería implementar el mecanismo de `notificar nuevas ediciones`; técnicamente, es similar a las notificaciones ante mensajes nuevos (comentarios en las publicaciones o en el *chat*) que ya recibimos.

Cuando menos, dicha característica debería estar disponible como `☑ checkbox` en el diálogo de votar para cerrar.

Idealmente, debería de estar disponible **en todas las preguntas**.

Por supuesto, entiendo que habría que establecer un límite (diario y personal) en este último caso, y que ello puede implicar *demasiados* cambios en las bases de datos del *backend*.

En el caso de implementar dicha característica *solo* en el diálogo de cierre, entiendo que las modificaciones en las bases de datos del sistema son mínimas: los votos de cierre diarios son limitados, por lo que **nunca serán necesarias mas notificaciones que votos de cierre**. Creo que con *relativamente simples* modificaciones en el *backend* sería suficiente.

¿ Que os parecería una característica de este tipo ?

¿ Sería posible implementarla ?

Comment: totalmente de acuerdo. Como te comentaba en el chat, hoy mismo se me pasó esto por la cabeza. Quien cierre una pregunta, seguro que tiene una mejor valoración para decidir su reapertura. La notificacion en plan: "La pregunta (link aqui ) que cerraste está en proceso de reapertura"

Answer (score 12):

Es una idea interesante, mientras tanto puedes recibir notificaciones de un post editado usando [Stack Overflow Extras](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Interesante, no conocía ese recurso. +1

Comment: me gusta mucho la caracteristica de Side-by-Side editing.. pero siempre viene desactivada.. alguien sabe como hacer que cuando entres en edicion venga activada por defecto ?

Comment: hay version para la nueva barra de navegacion ?